# Getting primary phone number from Google Directory API to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api

I want to get some user data of our Google Apps for Work users to a Google Spreadsheet via the Directory API. I use the following Google Apps Script and it works so far:

```
function writeToSpreadsheet(){
      var values = [];
      var optionalArgs = {
        customer: 'my_customer',
        maxResults: 500,
        orderBy: 'email',
        viewType: 'domain_public'
      };
      var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs).users; //example: ignitesynergy.com
      for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
        values.push([users[i].id, users[i].name.familyName, users[i].name.givenName, users[i].primaryEmail, users[i].phones ]); //Look in the docs or use auto complete to see what you can access  
      }

      var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/liganova.com/spreadsheets/d/1HwSMiBjW9lAw55GJaTdW_LDUjkLiP473ntuV2DpIeqQ/';
      SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
```

But: The values in the column for the phone number looks like this:

```
{type=work, value=+123456789}
```

I only want to have the value in the column. When I try

```
users.phones[0].primary
```

I get an TypeError.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users.list is returning an array of phone number Objects, rather than just a plain number.  I can tell this by seeing the {type=.., value=..} notation you are getting, the {} indicates it is a javascript Object, and I see properties named type and value.

You'll need to loop over the phone number objects returned and identify the primary number with an If statement.

try something like this:

```
  for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
    var phone = '';
    for(var j in users[i].phones){
         if(users[i].phones[j].type == 'primary')
            phone = users[i].phones[j].value;
    }
    values.push([users[i].id, users[i].name.familyName, users[i].name.givenName, users[i].primaryEmail, phone ]); //Look in the docs or use auto complete to see what you can access  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cameron's answer great! However, the "type" should be set to a different value, something like 'mobile' to display the numeric phone only.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update

```
for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
var phone = '';
for(var j in users[i].phones){
     if(users[i].phones[j].type == 'mobile')
        phone = users[i].phones[j].value;
}
values.push([users[i].name.familyName, users[i].name.givenName, users[i].primaryEmail, phone ]);
}
```